# NameError: name 'freenect' is not defined

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kinect, xbox360

I am trying to execute a python code using a kinect
this is awesome.py:

```
from SimpleCV import * 
import freenect

cam = Kinect()
depth = cam.getDepth()
depth.show()
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awesome.py", line 2, in <module>
    import freenect
ImportError: No module named freenect
libusb: 0.460928 debug [libusb_exit] 
libusb: 0.461054 debug [usbi_remove_pollfd] remove fd 6
libusb: 0.461203 debug [usbi_remove_pollfd] remove fd 9
```

Comment: And what does the file `awesome.py` contain? The code you posted appears to have no relationship to the traceback.

Comment: Where is `freenect` defined?

Comment: the 'awesome.py' contin the code i posted

Comment: how i can defined freenect ?

Comment: @Rubik951, line 4 of your code is `while True:` while the error happens on `depth = freenect.sync_get_depth()[0]` which isn't part of your question's code. Please include all of awesome.py exactly.

Comment: i have written the exact code now, i have confused with another code

Comment: It looks like you need to `import freenect` if that is a library you're attempting to use.

Comment: Where is `freenect.py` located?

Comment: i dont really know @g.d.d.c suggested this

Comment: What is `freenect` and how have you installed it?

Comment: from here: [openKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started)

Comment: Has anyone tried to work with kinect through ubuntu and simplecv ?

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me. Note that you need to check if the names of your directories match mine. It depends on the Python versions you have installed:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/freenect.so /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/.
```

That freenect.so was installed by default on Python3, so I've linked to it from Python3.7, which is the default for my system.
You can find where it was installed by:

```
 find /usr/local/lib -iname freenect.so
```

Hope it helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Install:

[libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect)

Try:

> sudo python2 libfreenect/wrappers/python/demo_cv_async.py

Answer (score 0):

Install python-freenect and other necessary modules by first :
apt-cache search freenect 
And then you can select all libfreenect packages as per your convenience:
for this python code error:
sudo apt-get install python-freenect

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS